# L2 cache memory

Tags: hardware, cpu-cache

What's the difference between 2*512 KB L2 cache and 1 MB L2 cache?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Don't be surprised if your question gets closed.

Comment: Little rephrasing would made it a very good programming questions. Some people tend to live close to hardware ;)

Comment: Programmers don't need to know anything about hardware.  You type the code in, some magic happens, and your output comes out.  That's all you need to know.  It's not like anyone ever writes assembly anymore.  >_>

Comment: No one can know for sure.  However, the answers (accepted and other) seem wrong to me.  A 2*512KB cache would be two way (ie on a collision there are two storage locations).  Usually L2 is shared between CPUs so the answers below don't make sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First one could be dedicated for dual core, 512 KB each core and the second could be shared, if more than one core?

Comment: A single L2 cache shared by both cores is more difficult to implement.  That's why each core has its own L1 and typically L2 cache.  L3, when present, is typically shared since it is used less frequently and it is slower.

Comment: @BrianCarlton, is it possible to configure L2 cache used by any one core all the time in Cortex a9?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are talking about a 2-core processor, they could be two design choices for the second level of the memory hierarchy:

- 2*512 KB L2 cache: two private L2-caches.
- 1 MB L2 cache: L2-cache shared between the two cores.

For example, private L2 caches can be found at the processors of the [Sandy Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandy_Bridge) or the [K10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_K10) microarchitectures. Shared L2 caches can be found at the T1, T2 and T3 UltraSPARC processors (T4 has dedicated L2 caches).

Comment: is it possible to configure L2 cache used by any one core all the time in Cortex a9?